# How to get a selected text and URL from a browser and display in text box in my webapp?

Tags: javascript

I want to develop a webapp which will get any selected word and URL of the webpage and store in DB

Whenever I select a word in any tab the below code should run

```
    var URL=window.location.href.toString();
    console.log=(URL);
    var word= window.getSelection().toString();
    console.log=(word);
```

This URL and selection variable should be displayed in my text box in my webapp

screen shot of web page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/066Ze.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Can you give a use case? It sounds like you want a browser plugin. I suggest you look into developing a browser extension. You can start here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons

You cannot write javascript that accesses other tabs of other domains, so the best route would be to make a browser extension. You can write the extension such that it works in both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

```
Word:<input type="text" id="word"><br>  
Url:<input type="text" id="url"><br>
select
<button onclick="get()">button</button>   
<script>
  function get(){
var URL=window.location.href.toString();
    console.log(URL);
document.getElementById("url").value=URL;
    var word= window.getSelection().toString();
    console.log(word);
document.getElementById("word").value=word;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)? Here's one that might work for you:

```
javascript:myURL=window.location.href.toString();word=window.getSelection().toString();W=open('W');with(W){location.href='http://example.com/add_to_db?URL=' + myURL + '&word=' + word;void(x = 1)}
```

It doesn't run automatically. Select some text then hit the bookmarklet.